# telebot , Не отслеживаются нажатия кнопок, как исправить?

Tags: python, telebot

Не могу понять в чем проблема, код:

```
import telebot
from telebot import types 
client = telebot.TeleBot('token')
@client.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start(message):
    markup_inline = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    item_yes = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text= 'да', callback_data = 'yes')
    item_no = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text= 'нет', callback_data = 'no')

    markup_inline.add(item_yes,item_no)
    client.send_message(message.chat.id, ' 1123 ', reply_markup = markup_inline)

@client.callback_query_handler(func = lambda call: True)
def answer(call):
    if call.data == 'yes':
        markup_reply = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard = True)
        item_id = types,KeyboardButton(' мой id ')
        item_username = types.KeyboardButton('мое имя')

        markup_reply.add(item_id, item_username)
        client.send_message(call.message.chat.id, ' Нажмите на одну из кнопок',reply_markup = markup-reply)

client.polling()
```

Comment: Не знаю насчет того, почему не отслеживаются нажатия, но предлагаю заменить коллбэки на bool вместо str. Тогда проверить условие можно будет не `if call.data == 'yes'`, а `if call.data`